# Marking assembly as serializable?

Tags: asp.net, serialization, state, stateserver

I'm trying to make a website work with a state server, but I'm having issues where classes need to be marked as [Serializable] to work. Problem is we have tons of classes. It just seems like a red flag to mark all my classes as Serializable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of marking every class as Serializable, look for the ones that are being sent back and forth between your site and state service.  Hopefully that's a smaller list.

Comment: Ya, it ended up being a much smaller list. Was scared for a minute there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with Garrison Neely's answer in comment above:

> Instead of marking every class as Serializable, look for the ones that are being sent back and forth between your site and state service. Hopefully that's a smaller list. –  Garrison Neely Jul 12 at 20:50